# Is the following function Riemann integrable?

Tags: integration

Consider $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by:

$$f(x,y):=\arctan\frac{1}{x-y}\quad\forall x\neq y$$
$$f(x,x):=0$$

Is the function Riemann integrable in the square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$?

I just have no clue how to attack this, surely basic, exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Well,  this function has an uncountable number of discontinuities, so it should not be Riemann Integrable (assuming that same result holds for functions from $\mathbb R ^2$ as well as it does for $\mathbb R$

It is discontinuous on the entire diagonal of $[0,1]^2$,  since as you approach the diagonal when $x<y$,  you get the $\arctan (-\infty)=-\pi /2$,   whereas when you approach it when $x>y$,  you get $\arctan(\infty )=\pi /2 $,  neither of which is 0., and for a function to be Riemann integrable you must have at most a countable number of discontinuties.

Comment: I believe that, for a function to be Riemann integrable in a multidimensional space (in particular, in dimension 2), its discontinuities set must have measure zero. In this case, a line in $\mathbb{R^2}$ (like the diagonal $y=x$) does have measure zero, hence it shouldn't be a problem for the integrability. However, thanks for the answer, as I've thought that maybe by proving those are the only discontinuities we can prove the function is Riemann integrable.